# ¿Como recorrer obtener valores de un array php recursivamente?

Tags: php, array, frecuencia

Ocupo ayuda para saber recorrer un arreglo multidimensional en php y obtener sus valores. El arreglo corresponde a un menu de varios niveles.

En el Array de la imagen necesito extraer los ID del arreglo, y en caso de que un ID se encuentre dentro de un children, saber cual es su ID padre, ya que no todos los Items tiene hijos. Pondré un ejemplo mas abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el mismo arreglo en código.

```
[
    [
        "id"=>1,
        "children"=>[
            [
                "id"=>2,
                "children"=>[
                    [
                        "id"=>3,
                        "children"=>[
                            ["id"=>4]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "id"=>5
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id"=>6,
        "children"=>[
            [
                "id"=>7,
                "children"=>[
                    [
                        "id"=>8,
                        "children"=>[
                            [
                                "id"=>9
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "id"=>9
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Por ejemplo

```
[ ['id'=>1, 'parent' => null], ['id'=>2, 'parent' => 1], ['id'=>3, 'parent' => 2] ]
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código del array directamente en lugar de una imagen del arrray? Haría más fácil a la gente probar las cosas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una solución recursiva. La idea es crear una función que haga lo siguinte:

1. Atraviesa todos los elementos del array
2. Introduce en un array de salida su id y su padre (null para elementos del "raíz")
3. Si el nodo tiene "children"

   - Guarda el "id" del nodo
   - Atraviesa de manera recursiva los elementos de "children"
   - Introduce en el array de salida su "id" y el valor del padre (que ya no será null)
   - Vuelve al paso 3
4. Llama a la función que creaste con tu array pasando null como valor del "id" del padre

Así es como quedaría el código (comentado):

```
// encuentraParents: función recursiva para encontrar padres
// $entrada: array con elementos a procesar
// $salida: array de salida con el id del elemento y el id del padre
// $padre: id del padre del array $entrada que se procesa
function encuentraParents($entrada, &$salida, $padre) {
    // para cada elemento del array 
    foreach($entrada as $valor) {
        // añade una entrada al array de salida indicando su id y el de su padre
        $salida[] = array( "id" => $valor["id"], "parent" => $padre );

        // si el elemento tiene children
        if (isset($valor["children"] ) ) {
            // procesa los hijos recursivamente indicando el id del padre
            encuentraParents( $valor["children"], $salida, $valor["id"] );
        }
    }
}

// el array que compartiste en tu pregunta
$objeto = [
    [
        "id"=>1,
        "children"=>[
            [
                "id"=>2,
                "children"=>[
                    [
                        "id"=>3,
                        "children"=>[
                            ["id"=>4]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "id"=>5
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id"=>6,
        "children"=>[
            [
                "id"=>7,
                "children"=>[
                    [
                        "id"=>8,
                        "children"=>[
                            [
                                "id"=>9
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "id"=>9
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

// el array de salida donde tendrás los valores al terminar
$salida = array();

// llamada inicial a la función recursiva con null como id del padre
encuentraParents($objeto, $salida, null);
```

Si haces un `print_r` de `$salida` después de ejecutarse ese código, éste es el resultado que obtienes (aunque el orden puede variar):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent] => 6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent] => 7
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el siguiente código, espero pueda servirte de ayuda, fue tomando como base el `array_walk_recursive` de `php`.

Ojo: Observaras que te escribí "pasos", este es una guía, para que se entienda mejor como se va "leyendo" el script, al final del código lo entenderás mejor.

```
<?php 
    //Este es una simulación de tu Array
    $array = [0=>["id"=>1,"children"=>[0=>["id"=>2,"children"=>[0=>["id"=>3,"children"=>[0=>["id"=>3]]]]]]]];
    $ar = $arr = array(); //Se declaran 2 arrays que contendrán los valores que vamos a iterar.
    /*Creamos una función que se apoyará el recorrido recursivo (esto mas adelante lo vemos )*/
    function a($i){ //Paso 2
     global $ar; //Accedamos al array declarado fuera de este ámbito, por eso el; global
     array_push($ar,$i); //Agregamos en valor $i al arreglo $ar.
     array_walk_recursive($ar,'b'); //Ahora hacemos recursivo el arreglo que actualmente agregamos con la función b(que esta debajo). Paso 3
    }
    //Esta es la función b la cual hicimos uso hace 2 lineas que básicamente lo que hace es apoyar el método recurviso del arreglo ar

    function b($a,$b){ //Paso 4
     global $arr; //Accedemos al arreglo que esta declarado fuera del ambito
     $arr[$b] = ["id"=>$a,"parent"=>($b==0?null:$b)]; //El arreglo $arr le agregamos los valores que ocupas, estableciendo la estructura que tu ocupas.
    }
    array_walk_recursive($array,"a"); // Ahora aquí es donde inicia todo el script, ya que inicialmente va hacer recursivo el array llamado; $array, Observa que te voy a listar el como va "corriendo" todo el script; Paso 1
   echo "<pre>"; 
   print_r($ar); //Imprimimos los valores que contiene el Array $ar. Paso 6
   echo "</pre>"; 
?>
```

El resultado final será:

```
 Array(
[0]=>Array
    (
     [id]=> 1
     [parent]=>
    )
    [1]=>Array
    (
     [id]=> 2
     [parent]=>1
    )
[2]=>Array
    (
     [id]=> 3
     [parent]=>2
    )
[3]=>Array
    (
     [id]=> 3
     [parent]=>3
    )
)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Probe el código y en si funciona bien, solo tiene un pequeño detalle esperaba me ayudaras un poco más por favor.  Cuando un array tiene 2 hijos me dice que el parent del segundo hijo es su hermano. `[
                "id"=>2,
                "children"=>[
                    [
                        "id"=>3,
                        "children"=>[
                            ["id"=>4]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "id"=>5
                    ]
                ]
            ]`

Comment: Esto parece que devuelve  como padre el hermano anterior en lugar  de el padre del nodo

Answer (score 0):

Porque no pruebas a guardar todos los padres en un array, y todos los hijos en otro.

Te indico un ejemplo

```
$arrayDatos = array();//Este seria tu array
$arrayPadres = array();
$contPadres = 0;
$arrayHijos = array();
for ($a = 0; $a < sizeof($arrayDatos); $a++)
{
    $arrayPadres[$contPadres] = $arrayDatos[$a]['id];
    $contPadres++;
}
```

Con el de hijos haces lo mismo. Y luego recorres el for de padres y dentro el de hijos. Y si el idPadre del array de hijos corresponde con el id del array de padres, lo vas guardando en nuevo array, y asi tienes por cada idPadre todos los elementos hijos

Espero que te sirva